# Adding images to carousel

Tags: html, css

I am adding a carousel to my webpage. I have managed to use the flickity theme. It works, however when I tried to add images they don't appear. I am not sure how to add the images properly and get rid of the 1, 2, 3 that is currently displayed in each slide within the carousel. There are no errors in the console either.

This is my html

```
<section id="cities">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h2 class="section-heading">Destinations</h2>
        <hr class="my-4">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery js-flickity">
 <div class="gallery-cell"> <img src="img/ny.jpg" alt="First slide">
<h2>
 <span>New York</span>
</h2>
</div>

<div class="gallery-cell">
<img src="img/paris.jpg" alt="Second slide">
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
<h2>
    <span>Paris</span>
</h2>
</div>

<div class="gallery-cell">
<img src="img/london.jpg" alt="Third slide"> 
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
<h2>
    <span>London</span>
</h2>
</div>
</div>
</section>
```

This is my CSS

```
 .gallery-cell {
 width: 100%;
 height: 200px;
 margin-right: 10px;
 counter-increment: gallery-cell;
 }

  /* cell number */
 .gallery-cell:before {
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 content: counter(gallery-cell);
 line-height: 200px;
 font-size: 80px;
 color: white;
 }


 /* big buttons, no circle */
 .flickity-prev-next-button {
  width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: transparent;
 }
 /* arrow color */
 .flickity-prev-next-button .arrow {
  fill: white;
 }
 .flickity-prev-next-button.no-svg {
  color: white;
 }
 .flickity-prev-next-button:hover {
  background: transparent;
 }
 /* hide disabled button */
 .flickity-prev-next-button:disabled {
  display: none;
 }

 /* position dots in gallery */
.flickity-page-dots {
 bottom: 0px;
 }
 /* white circles */
 .flickity-page-dots .dot {
 width: 12px;
 height: 12px;
 opacity: 1;
 background: transparent;
 border: 2px solid white;
 }
/* fill-in selected dot */
.flickity-page-dots .dot.is-selected {
background: white;
}
```

If anyone has any ideas please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Is this Bootstrap 4?

Comment: @WebDevBooster No I don't think so, this is where I got it from https://codepen.io/anon/pen/opyVQm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That thing has an extremely poor documentation. Below is a working code snippet but to get it to work you need to:

Delete or comment out this part in the css:

```html
.gallery-cell:before {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  content: counter(gallery-cell);
  line-height: 200px;
  font-size: 80px;
  color: white;
 }
```

And adjust the height in this part:

```html
.gallery-cell {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #8C8;
  counter-increment: gallery-cell;
}
```

The background in the above snippet is the ugly green. So, you can delete that as well.

And here is the main snippet:

```html
<section id="cities">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">Destinations</h2>
                <hr class="my-4">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery js-flickity">
            <div class="gallery-cell">
                <img class="carousel-cell-image" src="https://picsum.photos/1280/520">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-cell">
                <img class="carousel-cell-image" src="https://picsum.photos/1280/510">
            </div>
            <div class="gallery-cell"><img class="carousel-cell-image" src="https://picsum.photos/1280/500"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Note: due to their extremely poor/non-existent documentation I couldn't see whether or not they support text alongside images. There are no examples with text on their website.

Comment: No this didn't work, when ever I load the page the images appear all together but then disappear when the page properly loads

Comment: I have updated my code snippet. Please try. This should work now. You had Bootstrap columns in wrong places.

Comment: When I refresh the page the images still appear for a second

Comment: I updated my code snippet and description. This thing has extremely poor or rather non-existent documentation. So, it's all guesswork + trial & error...

Comment: P.S. I wonder why you aren't using the native carousel feature in Bootstrap 4? I think it has all you'll ever need. You could certainly do what you originally had in mind with the native Bootstrap 4 carousel: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/#with-captions

Comment: This worked, thanks. The reason I didn't use bootstrap was because it was messing up with my other styles